# What does "Forty-two's not gonna beat me" mean?

Tags: meaning

Patrick Hill scored 70% in driving test for his job as cash truck employee.
Inside Fortico Security, an armoured truck company, Shirley collects money from
men around and Dana was shown counting the number of push ups being done by a man:

> Dana: Forty-one. **Forty-two's not gonna beat me**.
>
> Man: Fu*k off, Dana.

What does "Forty-two's not gonna beat me" mean?

Comment: Perhaps Dana can do 50 push-ups, which is more than 42, and 'man' is struggling. "Shirley collects money from men around" - perhaps it's a bet.

Comment: "in a driving test for his job as a cash truck employee".

Comment: @WeatherVane  I agree. The way the sequence adds various events makes it sound like it's setting a scene, maybe in a screen play.

Comment: It means Dana thinks she can do 42 push-ups. She won't let the difficulty of doing 42 push-ups beat her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement "Forty-two's not gonna beat me" spoken by Dana defines this question.

To beat her he must do more push up's than Dana has already done.

Dana has obviously done more than 42, However as bets have been taken on who will do the most push ups. Dana is discouraging the man from doing anymore. He has just completed 41.

> Dana is telling him that even if he does another push up he cannot beat her.

She is saying this in the hope that she will win.

Comment: **Betting** has nothing to do with **push ups**.